# How can I read & write "comments" metadata from .mp4 files with python?

Tags: python, comments, metadata, mp4

I'm trying to add comments to my video files based on the data they were created (e.g.: age of kids in the video) if they have no comments yet. I want to read the comments section in the file description of each file to make sure it's empty, then add a comment based on time of creation of the file. Simple enough to do manually in windows explorer (right-click->properties->Details->Description section->Comments).

I know how to get some metadata from most files with stat() like the creation date but I have not managed to get to the comments sections of .mp4 files.

```
from pathlib import Path

testDir = r"C:\temp\test"
current_dir = Path(testDir)

for current_file in current_dir.iterdir():
    info = current_file.stat()
    print(info.st_mtime)
    print(info.comments) # This just throws an 'os.stat_result' object has no attribute 'comments' error
```

Comment: Are you committed to using python?  [Exiftool](http://exiftool.org) can write to the comment tag in MP4/Mov files, though not MKVs.  You command would be something like `exiftool -if "not $comment" -comment="new comment" /path/to/files/`   Change double quotes to single quotes if on Mac/Linux.

Comment: Thanks @StarGeek, much appreciated. Exiftool actually has a python wrapper so after playing around with that I managed to get it to do what I want it to.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @StarGeek for pointing me in the right direction, as it turns out the [Exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) he suggested has a python wrapper called [PyExifTool](http://smarnach.github.io/pyexiftool/) that allows to control ExifTool with python.
I'm sharing my solution here in case anybody else is interested:

```
import exiftool

vidFile = r"C:\temp\test\2019-09-02 19.52.14.mp4"
with exiftool.ExifTool() as et:
    vidComment = et.get_tag("comment", vidFile)
    if vidComment is None or vidComment == "":
        newComment = '-comment="written by Pyexiftool"'
        et.execute(bytes(newComment, 'utf-8'), bytes(vidFile,"utf-8"))
```

Exiftool needs to be downloaded, renamed to just exiftool (without options) and the .exe file referenced in Path. 
PyExiftool needs to be present and imported.
One caveat: The first time comment is renamed it will not show up in Windows Explorer (don't know about Mac/Linux) even though it is present in metadata. I don't know why that is. However, after manually setting comment to anything it can be changed by exiftool and be visible in Windows Explorer.
Good enough for me at the moment, I can select and change comments of all files in a folder with one manual operation, then let python change the comments to something useful.